# T-SQL script goto can't find label

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This is my T-SQL script (an excerpt - the actual script is massive)

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tblDBVersion 
               WHERE tblDBVersion.Version = '1.10.0') 
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Database isnt at 1.10.0.  Upgrading.' 
    GOTO DBUpgrade1100
END

GOTO eof

DBUpgrade1100:
    -- TSQL Upgrade Script goes here --

eof:
    PRINT 'done'
```

Running this produces this error:

> Connecting to 10.96.68.30 as sa...
>
> Msg 133, Level 15, State 1, Line 77
>   A GOTO statement references the label 'eof' but the label has not been declared.
>   An error was encountered during execution of batch.
>   Exiting.
>   Disconnecting connection from 10.96.68.30 as sa...

Is there something in the `-- T-SQL Upgrade Script --` area that can derail the `eof:` label from being found, or am I just messing something else up?

Thanks all

Comment: Just a thought - but I suspect somewhere in your `TSQL Upgrade Script goes here` you have an extra `end` or something else that is terminating the script. See if it compiles with everything inside that script commented.

Comment: I think the reason why it bails is because in the script component there are GO statements, and the GO statements terminate the batch from my research :( trying to refactor it a bit (GOTO is yucky anyway)

Comment: Yes definitely. GO is the end of the batch, and you can not goto a label in a different batch.

Comment: Also, if you’re running this as sa, stop.

Comment: It's on my dev server, the place where am developing the tsql script to give to the dba's. I'm running this as SA because its a local development instance.

Comment: `IF EXISTS () RETURN` or `IF NOT EXISTS BEGIN ... END ELSE BEGIN ... END` and get rid of all the `GOTO`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you can't use GOTO in scripts that use GO.  So this is what I did instead.

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.tblDBVersion WHERE Version = '1.10.1') THROW 50000, 'stopping script!', 1

The script stops if the SELECT statement returns any rows and does not proceed.   I don't get my conditional script but for me this is close enough and it works with scripts that have the GO statement.